# ThunderBird: Will it affect original mail account if any changes made in thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird

I have a doubt in Thunderbird.I configured my gmail account to ThunderBird.All the folders(including the custom folders that i created) in my gmail account came to thunderBird.
I deleted one of those custom folder from ThunderBird with an intention that this folder need not to be present in ThunderBird. But the **folder get deleted from gmail also**.

Other folders i unsubscribed (this method i found later)(*Is there any other way to do delete and all those things with out affecting actual gmail account*)

*My dbt is whatever i do with thunderbird will have same effect as if i am doing it in my gmail account??*I am new to Thunderbird and according to my knowledge it is for accessing mail accounts(reading new mails) etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to set up Thunderbird to interact with email servers.   One is pop3, where emails in the inbox of the remote server are copied to the local inbox.  You can then sort these emails into folders, but it will have no bearing on the remote server.  This is a one way mail protocol, from the server to the client.

The other way is to use IMAP, where the remote server hosts all of the email, and Thunderbird simple represents a view of the email and folder hierarchy on the remote server (though it does cache this locally so you can view and make changes while offline).

Consequently, when using IMAP, and changes made locally are reflected back to the remote server.

The method you have found for unsubscribing to folders is the correct approach, but any changes you make to subscribed folders will be reflected back to gmail.

Comment: tnkz.is it possible to subscribe only unread mails in inbox rather than all read mails ?